# Store file_put_contents file in a safe location

Tags: php

Currently, I'm connecting to a database using the following:

```
    <?php

    try
    {
        $dbh = new PDO(
            'mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=databaseName',
            'databaseUser',
            'databaseUserPassword');

        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo "I'm sorry, Dave. I'm afraid I can't do that.";
        file_put_contents('PDOErrors.txt', "\n" . $e->getMessage(), FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
    }

    ?>
```

This writes the text file to the same location of this PHP file, which is publicly available on my website. While this location isn't explicitly disclosed to the user, if someone found this location (i.e. example.com/PDOErrors.txt) then they would be able to view the contents of that file just fine.

My question(s): is this the correct way to handle this? Can I password protect the directory? Can I write this file somewhere outside of the website that isn't publicly available (like the root folder above the website)?

I need to be able to access the PHP file to access my database (I'm doing this inside of a game for leaderboard type stuff) but the output file should only be available to me.

Comment: Simple answer: If you don't want something available over the web, then don't put it into a place that's accessible via the web. Never EVER store anything "private" inside the document root of a website.

Comment: The only files in your doc root should be public files and nothing more. In most cases you would only find a `/img`, `/js`, `/styles` and a `/index.php` in there which contains only `<?php require __DIR__ . '/../bootstrap.php';`

Comment: I wouldn't go about in using password protection, because what risks in happening, is that each time you/the script will want to write to the file, it's going to ask for a password each time. It's best just to place it out of `public` altogether and bury it deep inside any other external folder than `public`. There are other ways I'm sure, but that's one of them.

Comment: You could though, use an [**`php/ftp`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.ftp.php) connection with a username and password inside your code, which is another option. That way, it will first connect, then on successful login, it would then write to file, using conditional statements also. CURL would also be another method, but not 100% sure about that one though; worth looking into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way to do that is to put everything that should not be accessible from outside in a folder which can't be reached.

For example you have that structure:

```
/nameofproject
  - /data
    - /logs
  - /library
  - /public
    - index.php <- www.example.com would point to this
```

Then you would have to configure your vhost and your .htaccess. You could look at Symfony 2 or Zend Framework 2 how they did that.

Answer (score 0):

.htacces code for your protected folder:

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
```

Comment: Now I move my website to an nginx server. What now?

Comment: I'm curious to know about what you said, concerning `nginx` @PeeHaa

Comment: Pretty simple @Fred-ii- there is no support for htaccess files whatsoever in nginx :)

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that (till now) Thanks, that one is surely "noted". @PeeHaa